# How to pass a ts object to R via RSRuby

Tags: ruby, r

I've had absolutely no luck working with the HoltWinters function via RSRuby and R.  How exactly do you 1) create a time series object through RSRuby and 2) successfully pass that to HoltWinters to get output?

Example:

```
@r = RSRuby.instance
=> #<RSRuby:0x106bfe6c0 @proc_table={}, @class_table={}, @default_mode=-1, @cache={"get"=>#<RObj:0x106bfe580>, "helpfun"=>#<RObj:0x106bfd3d8>, "help"=>#<RObj:0x106bfd3d8>, "NaN"=>NaN, "FALSE"=>false, "TRUE"=>true, "F"=>false, "NA"=>-2147483648, "eval"=>#<RObj:0x106bfdf18>, "T"=>true, "parse"=>#<RObj:0x106bfe0d0>}, @caching=true>
@r.assign('mytime',@r.ts(:data => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34], :frequency => 12, :start => [1993,3], :end => [1995,3]))
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
@r.HoltWinters(@r.mytime)
    RException: Error in decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) : 
    time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

rsruby (0.5.1.1)

R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)

Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

**:edit:** a similar example inside R only... if I could get any output from HoltWinters via RSRuby (other than an error) I'd be very happy

```
> z <- ts(1:34, frequency = 12, start = c(1993,3), end = c(1995,3))
> z
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1993           1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
1994  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22
1995  23  24  25                                    
> HoltWinters(z)
Holt-Winters exponential smoothing with trend and additive seasonal component.

Call:
 HoltWinters(x = z) 

Smoothing parameters:
 alpha:  1 
 beta :  0 
 gamma:  0 

Coefficients:
             [,1]
a    2.500000e+01
b    1.000000e+00
s1  -8.141636e-16
s2  -8.141636e-16
s3   9.621933e-16
s4   2.738550e-15
s5  -8.141636e-16
s6  -8.141636e-16
s7   7.401487e-17
s8  -8.141636e-16
s9   9.621933e-16
s10 -8.141636e-16
s11 -8.141636e-16
s12  9.621933e-16
```

Comment: I've never used R, but if it is convenient to check whether the equivalent R code is valid, then you may want to do that. If the equivalent R code is valid, then you may want to post that in the question.

Comment: Added an example in R that matches the example in RSRuby. Would love to see any output other than an error from HoltWinters when used in RSRuby (the few other methods I use in RSRuby like t_test work fine, can't vouch for them all). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you are really looking for guidance on using a specific interface. Up front, let me tell you that I don't use RSRuby, but I do use a different utility for R and Ruby integration.

Upon further examination, I see you really want a time series option... Which I believe... Yes, that can easily be produced from a dataframe by using the `as.ts(data_frame)` fxn.
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/ts.html

What I've used is simple enough.  If this is a major issue, maybe this can be of use to you.

```
require 'rserve/simpler'
r_object = Rserve::Simpler.new
```

What I do next is to take a Hash where the keys correspond to dataframe columns, and the values are arrays, and I run the `Rserve::Simpler` fxn `Hash.to_dataframe` on them so that they are ready to be converted.

```
data = Hash.new()#insert data here
datafr = data.to_dataframe
r_object.converse(df: datafr) do 
  %Q{df$time <- strptime(as.character(df$time), "%Y-%m-%d %X")
     df$name <- factor(df$name)
  }
end
```

This uses straight R code in the converse block and handles everything nicely.  I haven't tried this with your particular issue, but I know that this worked for me to import time data (Ruby `Datetime` class) from an array into R so that I could graph it.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'll be able to test tomorrow and will reply again then. Looks like I'll need to massage this example into RSRuby syntax, but it might do the trick.

Comment: @Charles  Did you try anything with this?  Or did something else end up working for you?  I hadn't heard and the curiosity was killing me!

Comment: Hi @Ryanmt, is it possible to call an R file directly using RserverSimpler and get the results back to ruby ?

Comment: You can.  From http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r#Progr_run

Executing an R script from the R console: `source("my_script.R")`

Basically, you can run any arbitrary command from Rserve.  I'm not sure you won't want to either rewrite, or direct the R output to a file though, as you won't capture everything unless your R script specifically returns everything at the end of its execution.