# integrating R with Rsruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r

I was wondering if anyone possibly had any experience integrating R into Rails, specifically, on heroku. I am familiar with the rsruby gem, which is the de facto (perhaps only) binding that ruby has with R, but documentation on integrating R with Rails is sparse if not nonexistent. Would it be feasible to, let's say, install R into the lib folder of a Rails application and use rsruby to access it through Rails?

Comment: I have zero experience with Ruby, but I can offer some advice on looking for R related help. Try searching for RSRuby on rseek.org. [This](http://www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753%3Aboaz1reyxd4&newwindow=1&q=rsruby+rails&sa=Search+functions%2C+lists%2C+and+more&cof=FORID%3A11&siteurl=www.rseek.org%2F) link may have some useful information.

Comment: it actually does have some helpful information. Thank you!

Comment: Though I would still love to hear from anyone who has experience in this specific issue themselves :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Rserve with a wrapper which simplifies the interface, called Rserve-simpler.
http://rubygems.org/gems/rserve-simpler .   It makes my life easier.  I end up using R and Ruby together quite often.

Here is a question where I've explained some usage.  [How to pass a ts object to R via RSRuby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504249/how-to-pass-a-ts-object-to-r-via-rsruby/6589864#6589864)

Comment: are you using this with vanilla ruby or on top of a rails platform?

Comment: @hank42 On top of a Rails platform.  It is loosely integrated, in that occasionally I'll use Rails to start a Green Threaded Rserve utilizing process, but usually the Rserve stuff is done first and given to Rails to display later.

Comment: ah, see that's a crucial difference. I'm going to need the R processing stuff to be done synchronously.. which I think is going to be a huge pain in the butt :(

Comment: Not really... I think you can pull it off.  Here's my thought.  Rserve creates a running instance of R, which it passes messages to and from via TCP/IP, in my understanding.  So, you just instantiate the connection, and then leave it running. You can send it whatever you want whenever you want... Actually, that's a great idea!  I hadn't considered doing it that way, but it actually is kinda beautiful.  I still probably won't, because I don't need R that way, but that should work rather well!

Comment: I hope you're right (about it working well, haha). But yeah, I don't think leaving the connection open is going to be a problem. I found this article pretty interesting [link](http://www.ci.tuwien.ac.at/Conferences/DSC-2003/Proceedings/Urbanek.pdf), but I'm guessing you've probably already read it..

Comment: @hank42 Interestingly enough... I hadn't read it, thanks for the link.  I hope things work!

Comment: @hank42 I thought I should make sure this is clear... Just in case it is pertinent.  The Rserve-simpler I referenced uses a pure ruby implementation of Rserve, rather than the Java one explained by that paper.

Comment: @hank42 I haven't tried it yet but did you manage to make it work on Heroku? thanks in advance

Comment: @nguyen-chien-cong No I eventually came to the conclusion that running R out of the lib directory of a rails app wasn't going to work since heroku has a max slug size of 100 megabytes, which is smaller than the size of R.

Comment: @nguyen-chien-cong I decided that it's probably best to do heavy statistical calculations on a remote python server which would function as an api to the main rails app, and do all the visualizations (charts and stuff) in javascript with d3, the svg manipulation library. If you really need R on heroku, I would probably look into the R buildpack that VirtualStaticVoid mentioned, which sounds pretty promising.

Comment: @hank42 Thanks, I already had a peek at that! Btw you can check my fork if you want R with Rserve on Heroku (https://github.com/nguyenchiencong/heroku-buildpack-r). Cheers and thanks for the reply.

Comment: @hank42 btw hank do you have an adress email or sth. I have sth that I want to ask you privately. Thanks man

Comment: @nguyen-chien-cong sure, you can reach me via email  han at therubyists dot org

Answer (score 2):

I created a [Heroku Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) to make using R on Heroku a no-brainer.

Checkout the [heroku-buildpack-r](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I explored R/Rails integration a couple of years ago, so my posts will be out of date by now.  However, they're still available and might be useful if you want to read them:

[RSRuby and Rails revisited](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2009/07/24/rsruby-and-rails-revisited/).

One issue I encountered was a "stack smashing error" on terminating the development server, which made me nervous as to whether the project was worth pursuing.

I have not tried deployment to Heroku.  In principle, I like your idea of putting R in the Rails lib/, but I'm not sure if it would work.

In general, I find that bridging other languages with R is troublesome.  It might be better to keep the two separate, by running R on a server (using *e.g.* [RApache](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rapache/)) and passing data back/forth between that and the Rails app (*e.g.* as JSON).  Another post that I wrote on that idea:

[Getting your web application and R(Apache) to talk to each other](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/getting-your-web-application-and-rapache-to-talk-to-each-other/)

Comment: I appreciate the advice. Funny thing is that, while digging around trying to figure this out, I ran into your older post. It was helpful, though not directly addressing the issues I personally have. What's interesting is the fact that this R-Rails integration stuff seems like an obvious issue to me and it's surprising how little information there is on this.

Comment: and yeah, I think I am going to have to keep them separate. Do you know of any good AMI's which have R pre-configured for this kind of stuff?